# Symbol.Barcode2 not found

Tags: c#, barcode, barcode-scanner, motorola-emdk

I am working on an application for Motorola MC92NO. When I run the application, it works up until when you click on something that involves using the `Barcode` function. When you click on something that uses barcode functions, I get the following error message:

> Error
>   An unexpected error has occurred in InventoryTracking.exe.
>   Select quit and then restart this program, or select details for more information.
>   File or Assembly name 'Symbol.Barcode2, Version = 2.9.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 6asdasdasfasdfasdf', or one of its dependencies, was not found.

When I select details, I get

> TypeLoadException

And the same message as earlier.
I am very new to this and have been stumped about this issue.

It is important to note that, this device I am using is an IT test device and has been played around with a lot. For instance, I had a `SQLServerException` issue before this and that was because this device was missing some SQL `.cab` files. I got the `.cab` files from my boss and installed SQL Server and that problem is gone now.

So, do you guys think I am probably missing the barcode program as well? When I press the trigger, I see the laser beam. So I don't know.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: If you aren't running your program, but pressing the trigger still causes the laser beam to glow, it probably means DataWedge is running. DataWedge is a tool that can convert scanned barcodes into keypresses. You should probably disable it if you're going to interface to the EMDK directly in your program. It shouldn't cause the `TypeLoadException`, though. Have you tried manually copying the `Symbol.Xxx` libraries to device, in the folder the application is installed to?

Comment: Wow. I've been enabling data wedge manually because I thought I was supposed to. Thank you for that. I'll try copying the libraries tomorrow and see if that works.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Amazing. I disabled data wedge (even though you said it does not help my error) and copied Symbol.Barcode.dll, Symbol.Barcode2.dll, and their respective xml files. Pasted it in the folder the application is installed to. Works like a charm now.

I really appreciate it. You just saved me several hours of distress. Thank you.

Comment: Good to hear you solved the problem! I've written my comment as an answer, should you want to close this question.

Comment: Yes I would, actually. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that you copy the `Symbol.Xxx` libraries to your device, in the folder the application is installed.

These libraries are needed to translate .NET requests to the native barcode libraries.